# Deep linking to UPI apps like Google Pay from webapp

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, deep-linking, upi

I am trying to deep-link to specific UPI app such as Google pay installed on the user's phone. For example, if the user taps on the Google pay icon on the web app, he should be directly redirected to the Google pay app installed on his phone, similarly, if he taps on other UPI payment app he should be redirected to that specific app.

I am sure this is possible in Android, but not sure how can this be done on web.

Answer (score 0):

Google pay accepts intent parameters for deep linking, check the [link](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments), not sure about other UPI if they accepts intent parameters for deep linking